# How to update with TableAdapter?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, dataset

I'm writing a program in `WindowsApplication` which use database.
I display the database values with `DataGridView`.
Currently, I want that there would be a possibility to update the database through the `DataGridView`, therefore I wrote this code:

```
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'databaseDataSet1.products' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.productsTableAdapter1.Fill(this.databaseDataSet1.products);
    }

    private void upButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.productsTableAdapter1.Update(this.databaseDataSet1.products);
        MessageBox.Show("הנתונים עודכנו בהצלחה!");
    }
```

The problem is that there is no update of the values into the database.
I'll be happy if someone could help me solve this problem, or even better, explain how to work with `DataGridView`, because I haven't found anything useful on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

```
        this.Validate();
        this.productsBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.productsTableAdapter1.Update(this.databaseDataSet1.products);
        //this.productsTableAdapter1.UpdateAll(this.databaseDataSet1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the datagridview to DataTable or BindingList object because they are observable.

Comment: What do you mean by saying I need to "bind the datagridview..." ?

Comment: You write something like this: dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable; Where dTable is an instance of DataTable(). Now you only need to modify the data table and it will reflect on the data grid view.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you fill the datagridview with a `DataTable` and a `DataAdapter` you could do the following:

```
private void SaveChanges()
{
    try
    {
        if (sqlDataAdapter != null && dataTable.GetChanges() != null)
            sqlDataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

This would auto-generate any insert, update or delete statements needed to update your database according to your DataTable

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    this.Validate();
    this.customersBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.customersTableAdapter.Update(this.northwindDataSet.Customers);
    MessageBox.Show("Update successful");
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Update failed");
}
```