# How to update database data in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm a complete C# noob so excuse this question, my to be employer asked me to create a simple database with insert,delete,update. So far I figured how to create a database and a dataset. I'm currently trying to implement the insert method to insert data into data base. when I run the program it adds the data just fine, but when I close the program and run it again or when I go to show table data it doesn't show any of the data that I added. here's my "insert" code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = int.Parse(iDTextBox.Text);
        string name = full_NameTextBox.Text;
        string pn = phone_NumberTextBox.Text;
        string em = emailTextBox.Text;
        string ad = addressTextBox.Text;
        tableTableAdapter.Insert(id, name, pn, em, ad);
        this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.employeesDatabaseDataSet.Table);

    }
```

Comment: The best guess we can make from this code and description is that you're operating on an empty local database file that gets copied to your output directory on every build.

Comment: Help yourself and learn "linq to entities". You then have a UI with the tables and instead of googling update database you google "linq to entities" update database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292727/how-to-update-with-tableadapter

Comment: For the sake of your own sanity, you may also want to look into repository and unit of work patterns, especially if you're ever going to work on larger projects.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `Update` on the `TableAdapter`:

```
this.tableTableAdapter.Update();
```

[Here's the TableAdapter docs.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms171919(v=VS.140).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a little too incomplete to provide a thorough answer but I suggest you learn about the System.Data.SqlClient namespace which will give you access to SqlCommand, SqlConnection and a slew of other items you will probably need to accomplish your task. You will more than likely end up adding

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

to your references at the top of your c#/code behind file.

MSDN: [System.Data.SqlClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient(v=vs.110).aspx)